# make page content cover and image when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

Im trying to do this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAUpiocVwMA where the content will cover an image when scrolling. The problem I'm having is that it is not a background image. It is an actual image tag. Here's what I have.

```
<section id="home" class="bgWrapper">
<img id="parallaxImg" class="bgImg" src="images/bg/bizlifter-design-bg.jpg">
<!--<div id="parallaxImg"></div>-->
<article id="signUp" class="areaMargin">
    <h1>Business smart</h1>
    <h3>One simple system for your business.</h3>
    <div class="purple"></div>
    <div id="signupRow">
        <input type="text" placeholder="    name@company.com">
        <a id="btn-start" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btnWhite" href="#">Start</a>
        <a id="btn-free" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btnWhite" href="#">It's free!</a>
    </div>
    <p class="forwardSlash"><span class="purpleText">
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    </span></p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg googleBtn" href="#">Sign Up Using Google</a>
</article>
```

The image I'm trying to cover is on the second line with id="parallaxImg".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it as shown in the video you can wrap your image into one div and wrap your content that is supposed to cover to image into another one. Having those two div's you can work with the CSS z-index. If you set the img-divs position to "fixed" it the text will be scroll to the top and the image will remain in its position.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: And by the way. In my opinion creating the effect shown in the video would even be easier by changing the img into a div and giving this this a background image in css. Then wrap all the items that are supposed to overscroll the image into one div and give it a z-index.

Comment: Thank you that was so much simpler. I placed the image as a bg in css like you suggested and added background-attachment:fixed and didn't even need the z-index. Thanks again for you speedy response, i really appreciate it/